# html elements appended twice in ie9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

The following script works alright in most browsers except ie9.

In ie9 two rows of divs are displayed. However, the dom only shows one row.

Is there something special to be considered for ie9?

Thanks for your attention.

```
$(function() {
var $window = $(window);
var hasPrepended = false;
var portDivs = ['<div class="port1"></div>','<div class="port2"></div>','<div class="port3"></div>',
 '<div class="port4"></div>','<div class="port5"></div>','<div class="port6"></div>'];
cfunction portraits() {
if (($window.width() >= 440) && ($window.width() <= 640)){//start if
  if ( hasPrepended === true ) {
       return;
    }

   hasPrepended = true;
   var portrait_C = $('<div class="portrait-C"></div>');
   $( ".page-id-28 .inhalt, .page-id-45 .inhalt" ).prepend(portrait_C).hide().fadeIn('slow');
for (var portIdx = 0; portIdx <= portDivs.length; portIdx++)// start for
{
    var div = portDivs[portIdx];
    $( ".portrait-C" ).append(div);
}//ende for
}//ende if 
else{
    hasPrepended = false;
    $('.portrait-C').remove();
    }
}//end function portraits

$window.load(function() { portraits(); });
$window.resize(function() { portraits(); });
});
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle pls http://fiddle.jshell.net/

Comment: yes, i will but first i have to figure out how that works, thank you

Comment: jsfiddle added – see below. In order to see the effect, please resize the browser window. theo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a link to:
http://jsfiddle.net/timholz/zhean8pv/18/

```
$(function() {
var $window = $(window);
var hasPrepended = false;
var portDivs = ['<div class="port1"></div>','<div class="port2"></div>','<div class="port3"></div>',
 '<div class="port4"></div>','<div class="port5"></div>','<div class="port6"></div>'];
function portraits() {
if (($window.width() >= 440) && ($window.width() <= 640)){//start if
  if ( hasPrepended === true ) {
       return;
    }

   hasPrepended = true;
   var portrait_C = $('<div class="portrait-C"></div>');
   $( ".inhalt" ).prepend(portrait_C).hide().fadeIn('fast');//see original line below
for (var portIdx = 0; portIdx <= portDivs.length; portIdx++)// start for
{
    var div = portDivs[portIdx];
    $( ".portrait-C" ).append(div);
}//ende for
}//ende if 
else{
    hasPrepended = false;
    $('.portrait-C').fadeOut('fast', function(){ 

        $('.portrait-C').remove()});
    }
}//end function portraits

$window.load(function() { portraits(); });

$window.resize(function() { portraits(); });
});
```

instead of pictures i use colors
for simplicity i changed the original line

```
$( ".page-id-28 .inhalt, .page-id-45 .inhalt" ).prepend(portrait_C).hide().fadeIn('slow');//original line
```

resize the result window horizontally
i hope this illustrates the issue.
thank you

p.s.: In the mean time i could narrow the problem.
the selector used for prepend is the cause.
ie9 apparently has trouble with $('.page-id-28 .inhalt, .page-id-45 .inhalt');
it is doing it twice.
Is there a specific way to write selectors for ie9?

Comment: js fiddle added, in order to see the effect work, please resize the browser window.